# Idiomatic way of implementing nested matrices in golang

Tags: data-structures, matrix, go, graph-theory

1. I am trying to represent a hypergraph in memory. Are there any better data structures for this task beside nested matrices? A nested matrix is a matrix which can have elements of both the "native" type (let's say `int` for the sake of simplicity) and matrices.
2. This is the beginning of such a matrix. Are there any rough edges in the code, to make it look more idiomatic? How to make it look more idiomatic?

The code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Matricial interface {
    Put(interface{}, ...int)
    Get(...int) interface{}
}

type Matrix struct {
    Matricial
    values map[int]interface{}
}

func NewMatrix() *Matrix {
    m := &Matrix{}
    m.values = make(map[int]interface{})
    return m
}

func (m *Matrix) Set(atom interface{}, pos ...int) {
    firstdim := pos[0]
    if val, ok := m.values[firstdim]; ok {
        fmt.Println("map key exists", val)
        switch converted := val.(type) {
        case int:
            m.values[firstdim] = converted
        default:
            fmt.Println("ERR: unknown type: %T", val)
        }
    } else {
        if len(pos[1:]) > 0 {
            newm := NewMatrix()
            m.values[firstdim] = newm
            newm.Set(atom, pos[1:]...)
        } else {
            m.values[firstdim] = atom
        }
    }
}
func (m *Matrix) Get(pos ...int) interface{} {
    if len(pos) == 1 {
        return m.values[pos[0]]
    } else {
        switch accessor := m.values[pos[0]].(type) {
        case Matricial:
            return accessor.Get(pos[1:]...)
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    m := NewMatrix()
    m.Set(42, 2, 3, 4)
    m.Set(43, 0)
    fmt.Println(m.Get(2, 3))
    fmt.Println(m.Get(2, 3, 4))
    fmt.Println(m.Get(0))
}
```

The data structure **must** allow connecting hyperedges with other hyperedges (i.e. handling hyperedges as though they were nodes).

Comment: I think a specialized Trie might be better suited to what you want. Where instead of text prefixes, you have an index sequence prefix.

Comment: There's a good example in C++ here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348459/is-there-a-library-that-provides-a-directed-hypergraph-implementation-in-c . It may help point you in the right direction. Otherwise, your use of maps and slices is idiomatic for Go.

Answer (score 1):

1. A nested matrix (adopting your definition of the term) seems a reasonable representation for hypergraph, not knowing anything more about your application anyway.  An example Go implementation is the [power set](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#Go) example at Rosetta code.
2. It is not idiomatic to embed an interface.  For example, if you rename the Put method of Matricial to be Set, which is what I think you meant, then you can just delete the Matricial field of Matrix and your program produces the same output.